# How to sign the JW token with the production api for my authy application?

Tags: twilio-api, authy

I have set up everything for my clients to be able to register to my Authy application via scanning a QR code. The only thing is the QR code seems to be invalid and the reason is that I've done everything related to the JWT correct but I've missed one thing. The JW token must be signed with the application's production API key. However, I have no idea where or how to do this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xA0S.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your production API key is available in the settings for [your Authy application within the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/authy/applications).

[image: First go to your Authy application in the console, then go to settings. Your production API key is listed on the page under the application name and ID.]

As for how to sign the JWT with that token, you might have provide the code and information about any libraries that you are using to generate the JWT.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I knew how to find my API key but I was not aware that the signature of the JWT was supposed to be that key.

I had emailed authy support and they clarified and helped me out. 

However thank you yet again for your answer. 

This question is answered.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it sorted. :)